# CSS clip - rect(auto) vs inset(0)

Tags: css

I was previously using CSS clip like this..

```
clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto)
```

I am trying to move over to clip-path and have this..

```
-webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
```

This is not behaving the same way as clip did, reading through the docs it looks like using auto in clip is like not applying any clipping.

Is the clip-path inset doing to opposite in this instance, how can I make them the same?

My original  behaves like this..

```css
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}


.section {
  height:100vh;
}

.blue {
background:blue;
}

.menu_holder,
.footer {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}

.header,
.footer {
 background-color: #F97D9F;
}

.menu {
 position: fixed;
 top: 48px;
 right: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
 <div class="menu black">
  <img style="width:48px;height:48px;" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149176.svg">
 </div>
   
    <div class="section blue">
  <div class="header">
   <div class="menu_holder">
    <div class="menu white">
     <img style="width:48px;height:48px;" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149719.svg">
    </div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
    </div>
 
    <div class="section">
  content
    </div>
 
 <div class="section">
  content
    </div>

    <div class="section">
  <div class="footer">
   content
   <div class="menu white">
    <img style="width:48px;height:48px;" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149719.svg">
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

But with the new clip-path properties in, the reveal clipping fails to work

Comment: you can probably share a code where you highlight the difference and how you want it to behave

Comment: Sorry, my explanation is not great! Will modify post with code now